# Predis Error while reading line from server , timeout fix

Tags: redis, supervisord

I am using Redis with Daemon processes as well as in regular caching

- Daemon processes with supervisor (Laravel Redis queues)
- Regular caching as key value pair

`timeout=300`  is currently at my redis.conf file

It had been suggested to change it to `timeout=0` at several Git links (https://github.com/predis/predis/issues/33)

My concern is that, if I do a timeout as 0, the redis sever will not drop any connection

Over a period of time, I see chances of getting error of `max number of clients reached`

***Seeking advice for changing timeout --> 0 at redis.conf***

---

Currently, I get following error logs frequently (every 2-3 min) [timeout=300]

```
{"message":"Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://10.10.101.237:6379]","context":
{"exception":{"class":"Predis\\Connection\\ConnectionException","message":"Error while reading 
line from the server. 
[tcp://10.10.101.237:6379]","code":0,"file":"/var/www/api/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Ab
stractConnection.php:155"}},"level":400,"level_name":"ERROR","channel":"production","datetime":
{"date":"2020-09-23 07:14:01.207506","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia/Kolkata"},"extra":[]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had changed to `timeout = 0`

Everything is working fine with it !!!

PS: Posting this, post an observation of 2 months after change